# How to create a multitarget NuGet package with the content file included just once

Tags: c#, .net-core, binding, msbuild, nuget

I'm writing a .NET binding project for an external c++ library. Wanted to include the library into the nupkg file, so the user just have to install the package to use it. The library is platform dependent, built among other targets for x64 and arm64 processors. And NuGet has at least two target frameworks - net6.0 and net8.0
The problem is that nuget includes the library as content once for each .NET framework, and once in the root of package - 3 times! If the project targets `netstandard2.0` only, nupkg still contains the file twice. The library is pretty big, and so the package is at least 2 times bigger than the library itself even if built for single arch+os. I can't publish it on nuget.org where the size limit is about 250MB.

Current part of csproj file is here:

```xml
  <ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="library.so" Pack="true" CopyToOutputDirectory="PreserveNewest" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

and the resulting Nupkg file structure is here:

```
...
./contentFiles/any/net6.0/library.so
./contentFiles/any/net8.0/library.so
./content/library.so
...
```

The library is native and it is obviously the same for net6 and net8.
How to build a package, where the file is included just once? Or what are the recommendations how to avoid forcing the user to install the library manually?

Comment: Create another Nuget package only containing the unmanaged stuff mark it as for example beeing for netstandard2.0 and reference that from the nuget package mentioned in your question. Maybe you even want to put the wrapping code that gets it usable in a managed environment into that other nuget package.

Comment: Thanks, but the wrapping .net lib already contains nothing than call to unmanaged library and unmarshalling result. Nuget targeting netstandard2.1 only still contains the library twice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you pack native libraries, instead of using `Content` (and related NuGet defaults), you may want to indicate a runtime-specific asset by specifying a "magic" path:

```
<None Include="library.so" Pack="true" PackagePath="runtimes/linux-x64/native/" />
```

This way, you can also speicfy multiple .so/.dll/.dylib files for different runtimes and the .NET SDK will choose the current one for builds and when publishing, a runtimes folder is included with the project with the host automatically choosing the correct one when run on the target platform.

See [Including native libraries in .NET packages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/create-packages/native-files-in-net-packages?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5002999) for more details.

There is also the possibility of doing a runtime-split - creating a NuGet package for specific runtime identifiers. While this is possible and was how parts of the first couple of versions of .NET Core were delivered, there is not really official documentation and support for this. It is also necessary that a `RuntimeIdentifier` or `RuntimeIdentifiers` are present at restore time of the consuming project (this should not be a problem unless you also use lock files for NuGet, then you should make sure you have `RuntimeIdentifiers` specified in the consuming project).

For this, a `runtimes.json` file in the package root (use a `None` item like above but set Package Path to `/`) can be added to the resulting package:

```
{
  "runtimes": {
    "linux-x64": {
      "libclang": {
        "mylib.runtime.linux-x64": "1.2.3"
      }
    },
    "osx-arm64": {
      "libclang": {
        "mylib.runtime.osx-arm64": "1.2.3"
      }
    },
    "osx-x64": {
      "libclang": {
        "mylib.runtime.osx-x64": "1.2.3"
      }
    },
    "win-x64": {
      "libclang": {
        "mylib.runtime.win-x64": "1.2.3"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Do note that there is no tooling that generates this file within NuGet, so you have to do that yourself either manually (or create your own automation).

Comment: the library is too big to include all possible variants into one package. Is it possible to build a nuget for each platform separately and one metapackage, referencing them, depending on a platform - Contoso.Native-linux-x64, Contoso.Native-osx-arm64, and a meta Nuget Contoso? So that if I add PackageReference to Contoso, it transitively adds Contoso-osx-arm64 only on mac, but not linux-x64 one?

Comment: Added some examples for the runtime split. It is possible but not really officially supported. You can use `libClang` als an example.